# Trying to figure out an error I'm getting on this nodejs + express API connection to Mongodb for signup

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to the Nodejs and MongoDB (and programming in general) and I haven't been able to figure out a problem I'm having.

The following file is a controller for signing users up and logging them in:

```js
const { getDb } = require('../dbClient');
const User = require("../models/user");
const { hashPassword, comparePasswords } = require('../hash');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const HttpError = require('../models/http-error');

async function signupHandler(req, res, next) {
  
  if (req.method !== 'POST') { return; }
  
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  //validate email and password is missing

  const db = getDb();

  let userExists; 
  try {
    userExists = await db.collection('users').findOne({ email: email })
  }
  
  //THIS IS THE BLOCK I AM ALWAYS GETTING IN
  catch(err) {
    const error = new HttpError('Signing in 1 failed, please retry later', 500)
    return next(error);
  }

  if (userExists) {
    res.status(422).json({message: 'Email is already registered'});
    return;
  }
  
  const hashedPassword = await hashPassword(password)    //why use await again?
      
  const user = new User(email, hashedPassword);
  try {
    await user.save();                                   //why use await again?
  }
  catch(err) {
    const error = new HttpError('Signing in 2 failed, please retry later', 500)
    return next(error);
  }
  
  let token;
  try {
    token = jwt.sign(
      { userId: user.id },
      'mysecretstring',
      {expiresIn: '1h'}
    );
  }
  catch(err) {
    const error = new HttpError('Signing in 3 failed, please retry later', 500)
    return next(error);
  }
  
  res.status(201).json({ userId: user.id, token: token });
  
};

async function loginHandler(req, res, next) {

  if (req.method !== 'POST') { return; }
  
  const  {email, password } = req.body;
  let userExists;
  try {
    userExists = await db.collection('users').findOne({ email: email })
  }
  catch(err) {
    const error = new HttpError('Logging in failed, please again later', 500);
    return next(error);
  }

  if (!userExists) {
    const error = new HttpError('Invalid credentials, please check username and password and retry', 401);
    return next(error);
  }

  let passwordIsValid = false;
  try {
    passwordIsValid = await comparePasswords(password, userExists.password);
  }
  catch(err) {
    const error = new HttpError('Invalid credentials, please check username and password and retry', 500);
    return next(error);
  }
  
  if (!passwordIsValid) {
    const error = new HttpError('Invalid credentials, please check username and password and retry', 401);
    return next(error);
  }

  let token;
  try {
    token = jwt.sign(
      { userId: user.id },
      'mysecretstring',
      {expiresIn: '1h'}
    );
  }
  catch(err) {
    const error = new HttpError('Logging in failed, please retry later', 500)
    return next(error);
  }

  res.json({ userId: user.id, token: token });
  
};

exports.signupHandler = signupHandler;
exports.loginHandler = loginHandler;
```

My code runs apparently without errors, but I must have done something wrong, because I am testing the signup functionality with postman and I keep getting inside the first catch block. This is the message logged in console:

```js
Error: Signing in 1 failed, please retry later
    at signupHandler (/home/sgu/code/ese/api/controllers/auth-controller.js:23:19)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/sgu/code/ese/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/sgu/code/ese/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/sgu/code/ese/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/sgu/code/ese/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/sgu/code/ese/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/sgu/code/ese/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/sgu/code/ese/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/sgu/code/ese/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/sgu/code/ese/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
```

That catch block is meant errors while trying to retrieve a user from the 'user' collection, but I cannot understand why I am getting it, because I do manage to successfully connect to mongodb atlas when I run app.js (the main file). I have no issue sharing other related files, but I believe the issue is in the file I shared. This is my connection to mongodb in case that might shed some light in the matter:

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const uri = 'mongodb+srv://<myuser>:<mypassword>@cluster0.ovzz5.mongodb.net/dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

const client = new MongoClient (uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

let _dbClient;

async function connectToDatabase(callback) {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    _dbClient = client.db;
    callback()
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(`Something bad happened: ${error}`)
  }
};

function getDb() {
  if (_dbClient) {
    return _dbClient;
  }
  throw 'No databse found';
};

exports.connectToDatabase = connectToDatabase;
exports.getDb = getDb;
```

What am I doing wrong?
Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you add `console.log(err)` inside the `catch` block and share the output?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan Thanks for your reply!! Sure:

TypeError: db.collection is not a function
    at signupHandler (/home/sgu/code/ese/api/controllers/auth-controller.js:20:27)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/sgu/code/ese/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/sgu/code/ese/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/sgu/code/ese/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/ro

Comment: `connectToDatabase` where are you calling this? Presuming in the index.js when you start the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not setting `_dbClient` properly. You should call the `db` method on the `client` object with the database name as the argument.

```
_dbClient = client.db('dbname')
```

Comment: It definitely helped, because now I didn't get inside that same catch block, but now I got inside the second catch block. I already console logged the error and got this: TypeError: getDb is not a function. Any ideas? Thanks so so much!!

Comment: I am referring to the catch block in line 39 "Signing in 2 failed...". Sure, but I don't know where i should perform that console.log

Comment: @simón That's super weird. "but I don't know where i should perform that console.log" - At the top after importing `getDb`?

Comment: I got this: [Function: getDb]

Comment: @simón Can you log the error and share the output with the stack trace?

Comment: Problem fixed!! I wasn't importing getDB correctly in my user model (which contains the save() method).

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this Arun!! I hope I can help you out some other time (though I doubnt it, you are years ahead of me, I wouldn't have known how to do the stack trace thing you asked). Have a very nice day and best of luck to you!!!

Comment: @simón Not sure if I understand. The `save` method doesn't come from `../models/user.js`. Are you using Mongoose?

Comment: Sorry Arun, i wasn't clear. I am not using mongoose, but I am still using models, so I do have a ..models/user.js, which is a class with a constructor to  create the user object and a method to save it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Just curious, why not use Mongoose?

Comment: mmm good question... I just felt it was too complicated, but I don't really have a good reason not to use it.

Comment: I just realized I'm having an issue with the jwt token after signup, would you mind giving me a hand with that?

Comment: @simón Gotcha. It really is easy to use. And you're welcome.

Comment: @simón Let me see. Can you share the error with the stack trace?

Comment: it doesn't seem to be an error. once the user has signed up, I send the following response: res.status(201).json({ userId: user.id, token: token });
but i'm only getting the token, not the userid

Comment: @simón Shouldn't it be `user._id`? I'm not sure how your `User#save` method works.

Comment: Fixed! I was using 'id' instead of '_id'. Mongodb saves the id with that undersocre

Comment: @simón Make sure to fix the `jwt.sign` call to use `user._id` as well.

Comment: Yes, I took care of it, thanks for the tip!! I'm going to start following you on github! Hopefully we can keep in touch